# Cant add image to Tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I'm trying to add an image to a Listbox, but instead of the image I see an entry called "pyimage1" in the Listbox. I've successfully displayed images using the Text and Label widgets, but I can't figure out the Listbox widget.

I checked the documentation but it doesn't indicate how to properly update a Listbox with an image.

What is the best method to add an image as a Listbox entry?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# test: lb_and_jpg.py

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import os

my_image_file = os.getcwd() + r'\logo.jpg'

class MainApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent
        self.main_container = Frame(parent)
        self.main_container.grid(row=0, rowspan=10, column=0, columnspan=20)

        # Defining frames
        self.left_frame = Frame(self.main_container)
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, rowspan=10, column=0, columnspan=5)

        self.right_frame = Frame(self.main_container)
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, rowspan=10, column=6, columnspan=14)

        self.left_listbox = Listbox(self.left_frame, height=10, width=5)
        self.left_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.right_listbox = Listbox(self.right_frame, height=10, width=14)
        self.right_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)

        my_img = Image.open(my_image_file)
        my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_img)

        self.right_listbox.insert(END, my_image)


root = Tk()
root.title("ListBox and JPG")
mainapp = MainApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Tkinter.Listbox` doesn't support this feature. Maybe you want `ttk.Treeview` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add images to the listbox. You will need to use another widget, such as the ttk.Treeview widget.

Comment: Okay, I'll check out ttk.Treeview. Thanks :)